# "Cannot POST " php

Tags: php, node.js, database, server, pug

I have obviously seen other threads related to the matter and couldn't solve my problem. I am not experienced with php. My file structure is like:

```
 -search/
    -index.jade
    -search.php
    css/
      index.css
```

My index.jade code:

```
    html
    head
      script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js')
      link(href="css/index.css", rel="stylesheet", type="text/css")

    body 

      form(id="search", method="POST", action="search.php")
        input(type="text",placeholder="Search for...",name="search_bar")
        input(type="submit",name="submit")
```

My search.php code:

```
<?php

$SQL_HOST = "peanuts";
$SQL_PSWD = "more_peanuts";
$SQL_USER = "peanuts_again";
$SQL_DB = "no_peanuts";

// jk...

try {
$link = new mysqli($SQL_HOST, $SQL_USER, $SQL_PSWD, $SQL_DB);  
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "PDO connection error: " . $e->getMessage();
exit(1);
}

$search = $_POST['search_bar']."*";

$search_query = $link->prepare("SELECT name FROM products WHERE MATCH(name) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)");
$search_query->bind_param('s', $search);
$search_query->execute();
$search_query->store_result();
$search_rows = $search_query->num_rows;
$search_query->bind_result($product_name);

if($search_rows > 0) {

while($search_query->fetch()) {

echo "Your search returned $search_rows results";
echo "$product_name <br>";

}

} 

else {

    echo "Your search returned no results, sorry :(";

}   

?>
```

I keep getting: "Cannot POST /search/search.php". Help?

Comment: `name="search_bar"` --- `$_POST['search']` I'd call that undefined index.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: “Notice: Undefined variable” and “Notice: Undefined index”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: Where is `records-search.php` coming in to play?

Comment: @JeffLambert Mistake.edited

Comment: @Fred-ii- I changed to $_POST['search_bar']. Would it be correct that way?

Comment: most likely, yes. Use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think I can't even go that far since all my php is not being processed...

Comment: how are you accessing this as, `http://localhost` or directly in your browser as `file:///`? is a webserver installed and php?

Comment: @Fred-ii- It is a node.js server. Not directly in the browser. I am using Jade to render.

Comment: I added the tag for it; I have never worked on that. See if someone else can see why it's not working for you. I won't be of any further help on this, sorry.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh. Thanks anyway